# Counterpart to JPA @PostPersist in NHibernate

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, events, jpa

I'm looking for a NHibernate (Version 3.2) counterpart to JPAs `@PostPersist` (Java):

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @PostPersist
    void someMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there something similar in NHibernate? The most similar I've found are [NHibernate Events](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events).

Comment: AFAIK you have to do it yourself with events since in NH there are a lot of more powerful alternatives to annotations and they are rarely used.

You could expand on the scenario and there might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but [castle active record](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/) should do this kind of work too.